# What does he mean by "immersion"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I was teaching Japanese to a (possibly American) guy. I gave him a tip, like, "The conjugation goes like this sometimes etc". Then he replied,

> Thank you so much! Knowing little things like this makes my **immersion** smooth. Otherwise, my anxiety issues won't let me continue my **immersion** unless I figure out the meaning of certain words in certain context.

What would he mean by immersion? Dictionary won't help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a better dictionary...

> the process of learning a language or skill by using nothing else but that language or skill:
>
> - We have all learned a complex set of grammar rules simply by immersion in a language since birth.
> - advocates of the immersion method of language learning

The quoted sentences sound a little awkward to me though. I wouldn't say "make my immersion smooth" or "continue my immersion" in quite that way.

Comment: Really? It's a paid Meriaam version.....Thank you,

Comment: @Kentaro That should work - I'm certain Merriam would have this definition.

Comment: "b: instruction based on extensive exposure to surroundings or conditions that are native or pertinent to the object of study
especially : **foreign language instruction in which only the language being taught is used**" [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immersion#:~:text=%3A%20the%20act%20of%20immersing%20or,absorbing%20involvement%20immersion%20in%20politics)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for both. Merriam's way of saying...I'm not fond of it, Anyway thank you.